# iOS sqlite storing null value without calling setValue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to store product in sqlite. When i setValue for database entity then i store correct value.

But problem is that i make a check if product is already in database then it should not add same product again. But next time it store NULL value in database.

Although i am not calling [addToFav setValue:@"My Value"];

Simply its check in for loop. When my loop runs it won't go in first condition where i make counter if(count == 0)

I don't know where from its storing NULL value. While i am not calling it any where else. So how its storing NULL value in database ?

```
- (IBAction)buttonAddToFavourite:(id)sender {
int count = 0;
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSError *error=nil;
NSManagedObject *addToFav = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Favourite" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSString *dish = [results objectForKey:@"id"];
fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"Favourite" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

for (NSManagedObject *info in fetchedObjects) {
    NSString *id1 = [info valueForKey:@"dishid"];

    if ([id1 isEqualToString:dish]) {
        count = count +1;
    }
}
if (count == 0) {
    [addToFav setValue:[results objectForKey:@"id"] forKey:@"dishid"];
    [CSNotificationView showInViewController:self
                                   tintColor:[UIColor greenColor]
                                       image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sucess"]
                                     message:@"Saved As Favourite."
                                    duration:2.0f];

    [self.permanentNotification setShowingActivity:YES];

}
else if (count > 0){
    [CSNotificationView showInViewController:self
                                   tintColor:[UIColor redColor]
                                       image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"warning"]
                                     message:@"Dish Already Added."
                                    duration:2.0f];

    [self.permanentNotification setShowingActivity:YES];

       }

if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

}

Comment: If you never enter the `count==0` branch then you have one or more Favourite entities whose `dishid` attribute is the same as the locally-scoped `dish` variable.  Is `dish` nil?  If so, then `count` will always be > 0 because you haven't initialized the Core Data entity attribute you're testing for.

Comment: But the problem is here. If i comment this line //[addToFav setValue:[results objectForKey:@"id"] forKey:@"dishid"];

Then its still storing NULL value.

Comment: So, what should the default value of the `dishid` should be? In the backing sqlite store, the column is NULL unless set.  In Core Data, you could  set up a different default value in the model editor.

Comment: I don't want to add any value in database id same product exist in database. Thats why if count is greater than 0 than this line of code //[addToFav setValue:[results objectForKey:@"id"] forKey:@"dishid"];

Will not run obviously. And if this code is not running then why value added in database. I am surprised about it

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction)buttonAddToFavourite:(id)sender {
  NSError *error = nil;
  NSString *dishId = results[@"id"];

  NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Favourite"];
  [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dishid == %@", dishId]];
  NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

  if (fetchedObjects.count) {
    [CSNotificationView showInViewController:self
                                   tintColor:[UIColor redColor]
                                       image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"warning"]
                                     message:@"Dish Already Added."
                                    duration:2.0f];

    [self.permanentNotification setShowingActivity:YES];
  }
  else {
    Favourite *obj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Favourite" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    obj.dishid = dishId;

    [CSNotificationView showInViewController:self
                               tintColor:[UIColor greenColor]
                                   image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sucess"]
                                 message:@"Saved As Favourite."
                                duration:2.0f];
    [self.permanentNotification setShowingActivity:YES];

    if (![context save:&error]) {
      NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You add same notification in both case. Can you verify this part where its showing notification alert. Whet should be done in first case and what happen in other case